# When report is exported to PDF the logo is black/look like corrupted

Tags: acumatica

I tried to export a standard SO form to pdf and as I check in it the logo/image looks like its been corrupted, as I look it in the report designer there seems no problem except that the cause might be on the Barcode Type. I just want to export it to PDF with a clear logo/image.

HELP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The report engine has issues with transparent colors when exported.  Any Transparent color comes out black when exported to PDF.

The easiest thing to do is to download your image, open it in an editor (even paint will work) and replace the transparent color with white.

Comment: Okay, yeah i tried a Jpeg image it worked fine. The only problem will be if the logo/image is transparent you'll convert it with white BG and embed it in the report.